# Indian mutual funds with tax benefits

Tags: taxes, india, mutual-funds, retirement

Are there any mutual funds offered by Indian banks that give any tax advantages? This is for my mother (retired Indian citizen).

Something that gives a better rate of return than the fixed deposits (ideally ~ 15%) and has some tax exemptions, at least for senior citizens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> mutual funds offered by Indian banks that give any tax advantages?

Banks directly cannot offer Mutual Funds. As the Fund House needs to be a separate legal entity. Yes there are quite a few Mutual Funds offered by Banks like State Bank of India, Canara , HDFC Mutual Fund, ICICI Mutual Fund, HSBC, Kotak, JPMC etc apart from leading international players like Franklin, Principal, Axa, Goldman, etc.

> has some tax exemptions, at least for senior citizens.

All fund houses have ELSS [Equity Linked Savings Scheme]. Investments in these schemes are tax free upto 150000. There is a lock-in period of 3 years.